# Why can the charge density be expressed as the Bloch wave integral in the Brillouin zone?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, solid-state-physics, charge

While watching Berry Phase, I saw a formula that says that in an insulating crystal the charge density can be written as：

[image: one]

I don't understand the second term, I know the wave function in it is a Bloch wave. As we understand it, it should be written as：
$$ 
\begin{align}
&\sum_{\mathbf{n}}\sum_{\mathbf{k}\,\mathrm{BZ}} |\psi_{n\,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})|^2 \\
=&\sum_{n} \dfrac{\int_{\mathrm{BZ}} |\psi_{n\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})|^2 
d\mathbf{k}}{d\mathbf{k}}\\
=&\dfrac{N\Omega}{(2\pi)^3}\sum_{n} \int_{\mathrm{BZ}} |\psi_{n\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})|^2 
d\mathbf{k}
\end{align}
$$
$\Omega$ is the primary cell volume, $\Omega^*$ is the Brillouin zone volume, and N is the number of primary cells in the crystal
$$
d\mathbf{k} = \dfrac{\Omega^*}{N}=\dfrac{\frac{(2\pi)^3}{\Omega}}{N} = \dfrac{(2\pi)^3}{N\Omega}
$$
Compared with the original formula, there is an extra lattice volume $N\Omega$, why is this?

Comment: You are trying to compute a function of $r$, yet you are integrating over $r$?  After the integration the  quantity no longer depends on $r$, so your formula cannot be correct..

Comment: @mikestone Yes, it should be in K space points, I was so sloppy yesterday. But I don't understand how that $\dfrac{1}{(2)^3}$ came out, I'm very confused? It should be the inverse Fourier transform of (), but I can't see where the inverse transform is

Comment: @mikestone I understand more than before and have revised the question. can you help answer the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are looking for a charge density you can't have integration over all space. You can however, for each point of space account for the "particle density" at that region, and that means a term like $|\psi|^2$.

Your wave function can be decomposed in the Bloch functions $\psi_{nk}$,thus you need to sum over **$n$** (accounts for electrons on every possible band), and integrate over all possible values of $k$, i.e. over the BZ (this accounts for every possible quasimomentum allowed for an electron).

Comment: Yes, it should be in K space points, I was so sloppy yesterday. But I don't understand how that $\dfrac{1}{(2\pi)^3}$ came out, I'm very confused? It should be the inverse Fourier transform of $\delta(\mathbf{k})$, but I can't see where the inverse transform is

Comment: I understand more than before and have revised the question. can you help answer the question

Comment: That factor is related to the density of states! Whenever you integrate over all $k$ states you sould be careful to remeber that the correct integral is something like $\int g(k) ... d^3 k$, where $g(k)$ is the density of states.

Comment: I think it should be the same thing as we said, the density of states $g(\mathbf{k})$ is the volume of the Brillouin zone divided by the number of reduce wave vectors $\dfrac{\Omega^*}{N}$